# 2 Ways of Javascript Get Requests Failing - Did I skip a step for calling APIs?

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I think I ams kipping steps in the process here becuase nothing is happening call wise. I put he same get request in postman, I got my response.

The following webpage:

> Debug - after the first fetch
>
> XMLHTTP Request has been reated and sent
>
> after the XMLHTTTRequest

was created by the following code in an index.html:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

//first try:
fetch("http://example.com/movies.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => document.write(json));
  //if this works, at some point, something shoudl be written to the console.
document.write("Debug - after the first fetch <br><br>")

//Second Try:
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://example.com/movies.json");
xhr.send();
xhr.responseType = "json";
document.write("XMLHTTP Request has been reated and sent")
xhr.onload = () => {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    document.write(xhr.response); 
  } else {
    document.write(`Error: ${xhr.status}`);
  }
  //something should be written out at some point

    

};
document.write("<br><br> after the XMLHTTTRequest");

</script>
</html>
```

Above - I tried to do a get request as stated above and its working in postman.

Comment: What do you see in the browser console? Look for something referencing CORS.

Comment: From the console (these two errors are showing up for both call basically):

Access to fetch at 'http://example.com/movies.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.  

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
index.html:6        Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at index.html:6:1

Comment: There you go. If `http://example.com/movies.json` is under your control, you need to add CORS headers. If it isn't, the API isn't intended to be called client-side like this.

Comment: How does one add CORS headers? (my first time hearing of this)

Comment: The answer to that will vary (depending on your webserver and/or language/framework); see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for a primer.

Comment: Thanks- any tips on how to do security tokens in javascript for APIs that require it?

Comment: It sounds a lot like you're using an API that's intended to be called server-side.

Comment: The API I'm calling can be called with Postman but it can't be called with my javascript code. I don't get it. The purpose of  http://example.com/movies.json is to teach people how to make API calls.
I don't have control over example.com

Comment: Postman is basically server-side. It's not happening in-browser, and thus is not subject to CORS restrictions.